# Returning two-level of relational data from WCF

Tags: wcf

I'm facing very weird issue. I've 3 tables. I'm using LINQ to SQL in WCF.

1. `Number` (It has `RankId` foreign key which is linked to `Rank` table)
2. `Rank` (`RankId` primary key)
3. `CategoryRank` (It has also `RankId` foreign key which is linked to `Rank` table)

I'm using WCF which is returning top 10 data from `Number` table. When I look at `n.Rank.Number` (where n is the object of Number class) and `n.Rank.CategoryRank` at WCF side, it's showing me properly filled data. But at the client side when I check `n.Rank.Number` (it's showing me data filled) where as `n.Rank.CategoryRank` is null.

I'm returning data as `List<Number>`. I also tried using load options but it didn't work. At the client side `HasAssignedOrLoadedValues` for `x.Rank.Number` is true where it's false for `x.Rank.CategoryRank`.

I've my serialization mode to `Unidirectional` and also child property is true between relational tables.

Can someone guide me what's wrong with this?

Regards,

Viresh

Comment: Can you **show us** the Linq-to-SQL query you're using on the server side??

Answer (score 1):

If Number is a LINQtoSQL generated type you probably don't need to share that type with the client, instead create a custom type that is a DataContract with DataMembers and map the values you want from Number to this custom type using either reflection or something like AutoMapper.  So instead you'd have the return value from the service as

```
List<CustomNumberType> instead.
```

It's obvious the n.Rank.CategoryRank is not being serialized.